# How to print java compiler error log using tools.jar compile method?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, tools.jar

In my idea IDE, I can see the compile error with red font in the console.But when I deploy the jar in the linux server.I can not see the compile log.How to print the compile error log?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        String compliePath="D:\\testFole";
        String filename="D:\\test.java";
        String[]  arg = new String[] { "-d", compliePath,  filename };
        System.out.println(com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(arg));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well if I got your question right, here is an approach to the outcome.
> I think this will be platform-independent.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    
    private static Process process;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        runCommand();
        getErrorMessage();

    }
        

    /**
     * This method executes/runs the commands
     */
    private static void runCommand()
    {
        File file = new File("D:\\\\test.java");
        
        String changeDirectory = "cmd start cmd.exe /c cd D:\\";
        String compile = " && javac D:\\test.java";
        String run = " && java "+file.getName().replace(".java","");
        String command = changeDirectory + compile + run;

        try {
               process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        }catch (IOException e){}
    }
        
    

    /**
     * This method will get the errorStream from process
     * and output it on the console.
     */
    private static void getErrorMessage()
    {  
     
         try (BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream())))
         {
             String line;
             
             if(errorReader.readLine() != null)
                while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);         //display error message
       
         }catch (IOException e){}
     }

}
```

Comment: If I use com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile() method ,can I print the compile log in the linux server when deploy the jar?